# Combination - Distribution of gifts.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Seven different type of gifts are to be distributed among $10$ children.
Every kind of gift must be at least given to one child. Then, how many combinations do we have?

Note:You have $A, A, A....$ (infinitely many), $B, B, B...$ (infinitely many), .... and distribute them to $10$ people with the restriction that the gifts got by people must have all types: $A, B, C, ...G$.​

I am totally clueless about how to start it.

Comment: How can you have infinitely many gifts to give when you only have seven at the start?

Comment: 7 are the types of gifts(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

Comment: Then you should edit your question to start "*Seven types of gifts*" ...

Comment: And if you have an infinite number of gifts to give, then you would have an infinite number of combinations, right?

Comment: It says that every kind of gift must be at least given to one child.

Comment: Right, but can each child get 2000 gifts?  Or just one each.  My guess is that each child gets one gift and each gift must be used at least once. For example: ABCDEFGGGG

Comment: I assume it is one gift per child. Lots of ways to do the counting. Maybe break into cases. (i) One type goes to $4$ children. (ii) One type goes to $3$, another to $2$. (iii) One type goes to $2$, another to $2$, another to $2$. Each case can be counted using standard tools. The $2$-$2$-$2$ case is easy to get wrong. Or, much fancier, count the number of onto functions from a $10$-element set to a $7$-element set, using Inclusion/Exclusion.  It would be useful to know what tools you have.

Comment: Are we to assume that each child receives one gift?

Comment: Assuming  only one gift per child, does it matter which gift a child gets ? Or are the children happy as long as they get one gift ?

Comment: Looking at it from a different angle: Rather than distributing gift among the children, the solution is to distribute $10$ children among $7$ types of gifts so that each type is received by at least one child. Seeing it this way, stars and bars is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to give out all seven types, then seven of your ten choices are forced. For the remaining three children, you can give any of the 7 kinds of gifts. Try using the Fundamental Counting Principle to answer how many ways there are to assign those three gifts

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one gift per child
with the **only** "restriction that the gifts got by people must have all types: A, B, C, ...G",
we can use stars and bars to get​ $\binom{10-1}{7-1} = 84$

**NOTE**

The question is not at all clear, and my answer is based on a set of assumptions I have made.

$1.$ Each child must get one (and only one) gift.
$2.$ For the donor, the child's identity doesn't matter, i.e. children are unlabelled.
$3.$ The children take wrapped packages randomly.
$4.$ The donor just wants to count distributions in which all 7 types are taken.

Comment: What OP means is highly unclear. I have treated the children as unlabelled for this problem, and gifts distributed randomly. In school, we were distributed toys in exactly this manner.  I have just taken that every child must get a toy, and counted the number of ways in which all 10 types get distributed.

Comment: Imagine instead, 10 (unlabelled) children taking one of packages colored    V, I, B, G, Y, O, R.

Comment: My last comment. If the answer according to the assumptions I have made is wrong, pl. let me know why.

Comment: You are correct.